# How to add header with recycler view in liner layout scroll horizontal

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV2zC.jpg)
header take space like other items in recycler view item
I want header to stuck in top and other item scroll horizontal

[output require like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLXuA.png)

Comment: Where is you're code?

Comment: Please share your code with question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.